# Model with mae gives nan predictions but gives reasonable predictions with mse. Why would this be?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

Same exact model in keras but i just changed the loss from mse to mae. First one works, but the second just gives nans as predictions. Huber also gives predictions, but mae does not.

Answer (score 0):

Removing clipnorm=1 from compile fixed it for me. Not sure why.